# jQuery .html() method does not update the HTML data

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am trying to update the database using jquery and ajax. A pop up window is opened for updating the fields. My problem is : the database is udapted fine but the values are not reflected on the web page without refreshing the page. I am using jquery .html() method to update the contents. 
Please help me with the problem.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" />
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $update_dialog = $("#update_dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen:false, 
        title:"Update Sub Sub Section", 
        width: '600px',
        modal:true, 
        buttons:[
            {text: "Submit", click: function() { $('form',$(this)).submit(); }},
            {text: "Cancel", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }},
        ]
    });

    $("#update_dialog form").submit(function() {
        var form = $(this);
        alert($(this).serialize());

        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(),function(data) {   

            var getbook = $('#book_'+data.id);

            $('.description',getbook).empty().html(data.description);

            $("#update_dialog").dialog('close');
        },'json');

        return false;
    });

    function edit3_link_action() {
        var getbook = $(this).closest('.book');

        //get id from div
        var id = getbook.attr('id').split('_');
        id = id[id.length-1];

        $('#update_dialog input[name="id"]').val(id);

        $('#update_dialog textarea[name="description"]').val($('.description',getbook).html());

        $update_dialog.dialog('open');
        return false;
    }

    $(".edit3").click(edit3_link_action);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <form name="userform" method="post">
<?php
$proposalid='P09-001';
$res=mysql_query("Select * from tblproposaldocsections where ProposalID='$proposalid' order by SortOrder;");
for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($res);$i++) 
{
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($res);

    if($row[1]!=$row[2])
    {
        $result=mysql_query("Select * from tblproposaldocsubsections where ProposalID='$proposalid' and InsertOrder='$row[1]' order by SortOrder;");
        for($k=0;$k<mysql_num_rows($result);$k++)
        {
            $row1=mysql_fetch_row($result);

            $exp=explode('.',$row1[2]);
            $alter=$row[2].'.'.$exp[1].'.'.$exp[2];
            $result1=mysql_query("Select * from tblproposaldocsubsections where ProposalID='$proposalid' and InsertOrder='$row1[2]' order by OrderID;");

            $lastsortorder= mysql_query("SELECT Max(SortOrder) FROM tblproposaldocsubsections where ProposalID='$proposalid' and InsertOrder='$row1[1]';")or die(mysql_error());
            $rr = mysql_fetch_row($lastsortorder);
            $lastsortorder = $rr[0];

            if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0)
            {
            ?>
            <br>
            <?php

                for($j=0;$j<mysql_num_rows($result1);$j++)
                {
                    $row2=mysql_fetch_row($result1);

                    $exp=explode('.',$row2[2]);

                    $alter=$row[2].'.'.$exp[1].'.'.$exp[2].'.'.$exp[3];

                    $lastsortorder= mysql_query("SELECT Max(SortOrder) FROM tblproposaldocsubsections where ProposalID='$proposalid' and InsertOrder='$row2[1]';")or die(mysql_error());
                    $rr = mysql_fetch_row($lastsortorder);
                    $lastsortorder = $rr[0];
                    ?>
                    <div class='book' id='book_<?php echo $row2[2];?>'>
                        <h3 class="title"><?php echo $alter;?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;subsubsection_<?php echo $row2[2];?></h3>
                        <p class='description'><?php echo $row2[3];?></p>
                        <a class="edit3" href="#">Edit</a>&nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <br>            
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
            <br>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
    echo('<br>');
}
?>
</table>  
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id='update_dialog'>
        <form action='edit.php' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Description:</td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name='description' cols='60' rows='5'></textarea>  
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' />
            <input type='hidden' name='proposalid' value="<?php echo $proposalid;?>" />   
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT by blasteralfred**

I used FireBug for debugging and the problem was the same as expected. DOM object is unable to read updated data. Is this declaration for getting the DOM element correct? This is the only problem !

```
 var getbook = $('#book_'+data.id);
```

This is how the  tag is declared:

```
<div class='book' id='book_<?php echo $row2[2];?>'>
<table width="80%" align="left">
<tr>
   <td width="10%"><?php echo $alter;?></td>
    <td width="70%" class="description"><?php echo $row2[3];?></td>
    <td width="10%" align="center"><a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please find ways to trim down the code? A good question has code samples, but not blobs of it, most of which are inapplicable to the problem.

Comment: `var getbook = $('#book_'+data.id);`  As far as I can tell, the corresponding HTML for this is `<input type='hidden' name='id' />`  In other words, you don't have any id set?

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment, data.id will be undefined in the javascript because your form does not have an id element with a value assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

If your .html() isn't working, its either because the element you're using it on isn't there or the value you're trying to set isn't defined.

You can figure out what's up by checking if the given element and the value are defined prior to the .html() call.  I'd recommend FireBug for debugging, but this can also be done simply by alert()ing the element and the value..

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems that the element I am using is undefined. The id attribute of the <div> is undefined. I cannot figure out whats wrong. I would appreciate if you could help me out. Below is the declaration code:

Comment: <div class='subsection' id='subsection_<?php echo $row1[2];?>'>
<table width="80%" class="tablesorter2" align="left"> 
  <tr>
  <td width="10%"><?php echo $alter;?></td>
   <td width="70%"><span class="description"><?php echo $row1[3];?></span></td>
<td width="10%" class="normalfont" align="center"><a href="#" class="edit2">Edit</a>&nbsp;</td>                              
             </tr>
              </table>
              </div>